# Data Binding with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-databinding

I am trying to use DataBinding in my existing project. As per the documentation I added below lines in app module's build.gradle and compiled the project.

```
 dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

I got the below error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugCompileClasspath'.
```

> Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0-alpha3.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         https://jitpack.io/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         https://jitpack.io/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0-alpha3.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/incnayak/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         https://jitpack.io/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         https://jitpack.io/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0-alpha3/baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>     Required by:
>         project :app > com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1
>         project :app > com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1

Can anybody help me in solving this? I am using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3.

My project level gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

App level gradle

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: "../constants.gradle"

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion project.ext.compileSdk
buildToolsVersion "${project.ext.buildtools}"
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

// Data Binding Library
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chanse.cee2048"
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion project.ext.targetSdk
        versionCode versionCodeNo
        versionName versionNameMajor + "." + versionNameMinor + "." + versionNamePatch + "." + versionNameBuild
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionNameSuffix ' (Beta)'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
//            debuggable true
//            shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
flavorDimensions "chanse"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minSdkDebug

        // Build only for english and xxhdpi density
        resConfigs ("en", "xxhdpi")


        // Have a different application name for dev version
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Chanse Games Dev"
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minSdk


        // Have a different application name for dev version
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Chanse Games"
    }
}
return void
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${project.ext.support_library_version}"
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1'
compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-4'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add these lines to your module-level build.gradle as dependencies; Android Studio 3.0 changed the way it pulls in libraries that you previously downloaded via the SDK manager - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1'
```

You may not need the second line, depending on how you use data binding.

Instead of `implementation`, you can also use the old `compile`. Using `implementation` will avoid build warnings going forward; it's a part of the new Gradle Java library plugin that the Android Gradle plugin uses by default now.

You will also need to add something like the following (typically in your module-level `build.gradle`) if you don't have it yet - this adds Google's new Maven repository for Android dependencies:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this needed? I thought dataBinding {
    enabled = true
} is enough. Can you show me the documentation saying this?

Comment: It was enough pre-3.0. In 3.0 things have changed. 3.0 is still alpha, so most documentation still describes the legacy ways. I've updated my answer with the key reference and additional info. Try it.

Comment: That's too bad. Did you make sure to include the new maven.google.com repository that I added to my answer? I can confirm that I have baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha3.jar, but I don't know where it came from. I see that for me baseLibrary-3.0.0-alpha2.jar came from maven.google.com, but I'm not sure where alpha3 came from.

Comment: Yeah, I have added that. Moreover, if you see my log, I am not finding maven.google.com in gradle's searching list. Is that a problem?

Comment: If I am removing dataBinding { enabled = true } and just adds the implementation details, I am getting error saying - Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.0-dev

Comment: You are still not seeing maven.google.com in that log after adding it as a repository? That is a problem. Can you post your complete project-level and module-level build.gradle files?

Comment: please check my updated question with full build.gradle source.

Comment: You did not actually add the correct repository. Look at your module-level build.gradle again.

Comment: Seems like working. But if it is declared in root gradle why it is needed again in app level gradle?

Comment: Thanks goodness. You added it under buildscript, which sets the Gradle repositories for the dependencies under buildscript, nothing else. If you add it under allprojects|repositories it will work. But I'd say in most cases it's preferable to add it in the module-level build.gradle, because you are dependent on Android dependencies only in Android-related modules, not Java library modules, etc. But that's a whole other topic.

Comment: I believe the maven repository should be added to your build.gradle project-level, instead of module-level if am not mistaken? @Uli