# Downloading Android Data Binding Library

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-sdk-manager

[image]
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

I wonder how to download the library from the Support repository in the Android SDK manager. It seems that I only have to set dataBinding to true in build.gradle file in the app module. Using Android Studio 2.3

Comment: yes adding--->   android { dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}   will solve your problem.

Comment: Once you move to Android Studio 3.0, you'll need to add a few more lines to your build.gradle - this will show you how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351697/data-binding-with-android-studio-3-0-canary-3/44355474#44355474

Comment: @PunitSharma, I see. thanks. The tutorial I followed was outdated, I think. It has "apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding' " in the gradle file
and also this line in the project gradle file: 



dependencies {
     classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4"
}

Comment: @Uli, I see. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data binding in your project by adding the below code in your app level `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true;
    }
}
```

You don't have to do anything more for data binding. You can also check this blog.

https://medium.com/@karmakar.avijit/android-data-binding-library-i-782d773de42c

Comment: if you plan to use data binding in a kotlin project you need to apply  the kotlin-kapt plugin in your build.gradle                                                                                                                   add  `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' ` at the top of your build.gradle